# Display a Dialog in a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, dialog, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to display my loader-dialog in a thread because when I start the upload system of my files I can't see the window until the processing is finished.

I tried something like this:

```
thread.start_new_thread(self.display_loader(),(self))
```

but it didn't work.

There is a special way to run a new window in a thread?

Everything is done with Python and PyGtk

Comment: Have you initialized threads for Gtk? [This](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show) be of some help

Answer (score 0):

When you say `self.display_thread()`, that will actually *call* the `display_thread` function right there, and pass its return value as the first argument to `thread.start_new_thread`. That's probably not what you intended.

That said, I think you're better off doing it the other way around; let the main thread own the UI, and do the loading off in a thread.

Remember that GTK+ is not very thread-safe, it's absolutely best to do *all* interaction with GTK+ from a *single* thread.

**UPDATE**: Actually, the above is perhaps over-simplifying a bit, it's the "common truth" as I've understood it (I've been using GTK+ for ~15 years but seldom with threads). [This article](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness) re-states it in a more forgiving way, not sure if it really makes life that much easier in this case, though. I wanted to mention in for completeness' sake.

Comment: what I want to do is to display my loader in a new thread, what the "display_loader()" does is:
loader.show()

Maybe I can try to run the uploader file in a thread and communicate with the loader every time I finished the upload.

What I want to do is a loader that tell you "I am uploading 1 of 10 files" and update this text each time I finished to upload a file